# sum up values and store it into array

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following results after multiplying the 2d array with the array.

```
76,0,38,7,32,0,16,18,32,0,16,18,0,0,0,19,16,0,8,23,76,0,38,25
```

now I want to add the value 2 by 2 and store it in another array(results[])
so it goes like

```
76 + 0 = 76(results[0])     
38 + 7 = 45(results[1)
32 + 0 = 32(results[2])
16 + 18 = 34(results[3])  
32 + 0 = 32(results[4])
16 + 18 = 34(results[5]) 
0 + 0 = 0(results[6])
0 + 19 = 19(results[7])
16 + 0 = 16(results[8])
8 + 23 = 31(results[9])
76 + 0 = 76(results[10])
38 + 25 = 63(results[11])
```

but i got this result instead which is wrong

```
114 
7
48
18
48
18
0
19
24
23
114
25
```

Please help.

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    int matrix[][]= { {4,0},
                            {2,1},

    };

    int array[] = {19,7,8,18,8,18,0,19,4,23,19,25};

    int result[] = new int[12]; 
    for (int count = 0; count < array.length; count+= matrix.length) {  
        for (int r = 0; r < matrix.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < matrix.length; c++) {
                result[count] += matrix[r][c] * array[count++];                 
            }
            count -= matrix.length;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add traces in the source code, learn to use your debugger. Divide the problems into methods doing just one thing. That's the daily job of developers. You should be able to do that by yourself. Your description says you have a single, 1D array, but that's not what the code is dealing with at all.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do here. Please explain the mathematical operation you want to perform with `matrix` and `array`

Comment: it's just after doing matrix[r][c] * array[count++] I will get serveral outputs. I want to add the output 2 at a time and store it into another array but the results i got is wrong and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results isn't correct, but I think you wanted something like

```
int matrix[][] = { { 4, 0 }, { 2, 1 } };
int array[] = { 19, 7, 8, 18, 8, 18, 0, 19, 4, 23, 19, 25 };
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int row = 0; row < matrix.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < matrix[0].length; col++) {
            result.add(array[i] * matrix[row][col]);
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(result); // <-- display the result of matrix multiplication.
// Add pairs.
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < result.size(); i += 2) {
    int a = result.get(i);
    int b = result.get(i + 1);
    int total = a + b;
    System.out.printf("%d. %d + %d = %d%n", i, a, b, total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have this array firstResults[] = {76,0,38,7,32,0,16,18,32,0,16,18,0,0,0,19,16,0,8,23,76,0,38,25};
and result[] = new int[12];

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
 result[i] = firstResults[0+(i*2)] + firstResults[1+(i*2)];
}
```

Comment: ok. but is there a way I can add two values each time after doing matrix[r][c] * array[count++] and store it into an array straight without needing to create a firstResult[] array then add from there?